# PYTHON Select command exiting me

Tags: python, select, sys

I'm relatively new to select and how it functions, and am trying to program a time-sensitive input. I have it set to print "code?" then after 3 seconds disappear and wait for input. But, after those 3 seconds, the code just exits.  This works on an online console like Repl but not in windows python console. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
print("code?")

time.sleep(3)

clear()

rlist, _ , _ = select([sys.stdin], [],[],timeout)

if rlist:

  clear()
```

Comment: `select` check values but it doesn't wait. You would have to run code in some loop to repeate `select` again and again. Beside maybe there was some in `sys.stdin`  so it didn't wait.

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and test. At this moment all question is useless and we can only downvote and close it.